# How to do a count over instances of 'replies'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently learning ruby, and i have an application where a user enters:

```
:name
:menu
:rsvp
```

They are all entered as a `reply`

I want to be able to get a count of how many people are currently added and display this on the index page. How would i go about getting a count to go over how many items are added to the database thus far?

**Reply.rb**

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :menu, :name, :rsvp, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                  :first_name, :last_name, :profile_name
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  has_many :replies

  def full_name
    first_name + " " + last_name
  end
end
```

**Replies Controller**

```
class RepliesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /replies
  # GET /replies.json
  def index
    @replies = Reply.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @replies }
    end
  end

  # GET /replies/1
  # GET /replies/1.json
  def show
    @reply = Reply.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @reply }
    end
  end

  # GET /replies/new
  # GET /replies/new.json
  def new
    @reply = Reply.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @reply }
    end
  end

  # GET /replies/1/edit
  def edit
    @reply = Reply.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /replies
  # POST /replies.json
  def create
    @reply = Reply.new(params[:reply])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reply.save
        format.html { redirect_to @reply, notice: 'Reply was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @reply, status: :created, location: @reply }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @reply.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /replies/1
  # PUT /replies/1.json
  def update
    @reply = Reply.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reply.update_attributes(params[:reply])
        format.html { redirect_to @reply, notice: 'Reply was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @reply.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /replies/1
  # DELETE /replies/1.json
  def destroy
    @reply = Reply.find(params[:id])
    @reply.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to replies_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

I hope this information is helpful.

Comment: You're going to have to share details of your relevant model and/or controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the User count:

```
User.count
```

In your controller, it's best to put this in an instance variable:

```
@user_count = User.count
```

To show it on a typical ERR view:

```
<%= @user_count %>
```

All the typical ActiveRecord models, controllers, and views work like this.

Comment: Ah thanks, this is brilliant. What if i wanted to get more complex. I was thinking about it and i could change my db to instead have the rsvp as a check_box integer instead of text, and then have a true / false value for attending / not attending. Then i just need a way to count the two different values. Is this getting a little too complex for where i'm at?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. In general, you can name your fields using a positive word (e.g. instead of naming the field "check_box" name it "attending") and make it a boolean, then you can do Reply.where(attending:true).count.